# Is the product of the sigmoid output positive definite kernel?

Tags: kernel-trick

$$K(x_i, x_j) = \sigma(x_i)*\sigma(x_j),$$ where $\sigma: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a sigmoid function. Is this kernel positive definite? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer is a demonstration in a more general setting: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600019/is-k-z-z-z-prime-sigmawtzb-sigmawtz-primeb-with-nonlinear-fu/600528#600528